# form not updating for specific record rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm trying to update a record with a button, by having and admin user tyoe confirm a record by clicking the confirm submit button with this form, but it would just update the first record in the database, not the specific one. Can i put "hour.id" in the form_for section to make it update the record i want it to?

index.html.erb form view

```
<% @allhours.each do |hour| %>
              <tr id="dashfield">
                <td><%= hour.user.first_name + " " +hour.user.last_name %></td>
                <td><%= hour.assignment %></td>
                <td><%= hour.hours %></td>
                <td><%= hour.supervisor %></td>
                <td><%= hour.date %></td>
                <td><%= link_to "confirm", edit_hour_path(hour.id, :status => 'confirmed')%></td>
              </tr>
          <% end %>
```

Controller

```
def index
    @allhours = HourLog.where(status:'pending')
  end
  def update
    @hour = HourLog.find_by(status:'pending')
    @hour.update_attribute(update_hour_params)
    redirect_to '/dashboard/hours'
  end
def edit
    @hour = HourLog.find(params[:id])
    @hour.update_attributes(update_hour_params)
    redirect_to '/dashboard/hours'
  end
```

hour_log model

```
class HourLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'welcome#index'
  get '/signup' => 'users#new'
  resources :users
  get '/dashboard/users' => 'users#index'
  put '/dashboard/users' => 'users#update'
  get '/login' => 'sessions#new'
  post '/login' => 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
  get '/dashboard' => 'hours#new'
  get '/dashboard/hours' => 'hours#index'
  put '/dashboard/hours' => 'hours#update'
  resources :hours
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This line :

```
@hour = HourLog.find_by(status:'pending')
```

will find the first Hourlog that is in pending status. You should pass the hourlog id in the form and use it in the controller

change the line in the routes :

```
put '/dashboard/hours/:id' => 'hours#update'
```

in the view :

```
<%= form_tag dashboard_hours_path(id:hour.id), method: :put do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :role, :value => 'confirm'%>
  <%= submit_tag 'Confirm'%>
<% end %>
```

in the controller :

```
@hour = HourLog.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: I tried, and got this error:   undefined method `hour_log_path' in Hours#index

Comment: I am using an index view with many records at once, so the id isn't specifies in the url

Comment: what is the generated url in the <form> tag ? (you should see using 'inspect')

Comment: I believe it is /dashboard/hours as in the routes

Comment: Edit : add id param to the route+ using form_tag instead of form_for (and adding _tag

Comment: i updated the view and controller, and this seems to work except is says the parameter hour_log is empty or missing, which is the database, and is definitely there. any solutions?

Comment: I fail my first edit and redo it, do you have the last one?

hmmm hour_log is empty? could you add stack trace by editing your question (at the end)?

Comment: sorry, but i don't know how to add a stack trace, or what a stack trace is

Comment: pp/views/hours/index.html.erb:61:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_hours_index_html_erb__695099359_27419400'
app/views/hours/index.html.erb:60:in `block in _app_views_hours_index_html_erb__695099359_27419400'
app/views/hours/index.html.erb:53:in `_app_views_hours_index_html_erb__695099359_27419400'

Comment: is it what i just commented?

Comment: yes and you can see it's written "index.html.erb" line 60, so then you should see what is happening into this line

Comment: ah, sorry wrong error. It says that the params is empty, using the code i have in my question with the link to edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87073/discussion-between-nicolas-maloeuvre-and-d-kucher).